# How do i get all the weekdays and dates in a month

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am trying to get all the weekdays of the selected Month along with the day like Monday or Tuesday, etc?? How is it possible? is there an inbuilt function that i do not know?

This is in C# 2.0, asp.net using VS 2005

Comment: what are you wanting the list type to be, a series of DateTime objects?

Comment: The date and the day like "15th and Monday" I want both the values.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your question. Can you please be more specific? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I make no guarantees about leap years, daylight savings jumps, special days, [Shanghai 1927](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result), etc.

```
public List<DateTime> getWeekdatesandDates(int Month, int Year)
{
    List<DateTime> weekdays = new List<DateTime>();

    DateTime firstOfMonth = new DateTime(Year, Month, 1);

    DateTime currentDay = firstOfMonth;
    while (firstOfMonth.Month == currentDay.Month)
    {
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = currentDay.DayOfWeek;
        if (dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            weekdays.Add(currentDay);

        currentDay = currentDay.AddDays(1);
    }

    return weekdays;
}
```

The resultant `DateTime` objects have a `DayOfWeek` property which you can check to see if it's Monday through Friday.

Comment: I haven't tested that, but according to the MSDN, the members I used are there in 2.0.

Comment: @Ram no, but you can explicitly declare the type. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is perfect and i learnt something today. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
private List<DateTime> getWeekDayDates(int month, int year)
{
    List<DateTime> weekdays = new List<DateTime>();
    DateTime basedt = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    while ((basedt.Month == month) && (basedt.Year == year))
    {
        if (basedt.DayOfWeek == (DayOfWeek.Monday | DayOfWeek.Tuesday | DayOfWeek.Wednesday | DayOfWeek.Thursday | DayOfWeek.Friday))
        {
            weekdays.Add(new DateTime(basedt.Year, basedt.Month, basedt.Day));
        }
        basedt = basedt.AddDays(1);
    }
    return weekdays;
}
```

Then you can get whatever info out of each DateTime you need.

Comment: That weekday check won't work that way. I suspect you want: `if ((basedt.DayOfWeek & (DayOfWeek.Monday | DayOfWeek.Tuesday | DayOfWeek.Wednesday | DayOfWeek.Thursday | DayOfWeek.Friday)) != 0)` or some equivalent. EDIT: And the year check I think is superfluous (I can think of no conditions in which the year would change but not the month)

Comment: I may have the dayofweek syntax wrong, i dont write clauses like that often, and i thought of the same thing on the year check, but figured why not.