# C# - program to display all of the same days dates in the month, user input

Tags: c#, date

i need guidance on how i can display for example all monday dates in a month, based on user input, can be any day and any month. 
my code so far is here but doesn't seem to display the dates. of the specified day i input, where has this gone wrong, any help is really appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Calendar
{
   class Program
   {
        static int promptDay = new int();
        static int year = new int();
        static int month = new int();
        static int[,] calendar = new int[6, 7];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the year? ");
            year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the month (January = 1, etc): ");
            month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the day you want to see the dates for (Mon = 0, etc): ");
            promptDay = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            DrawHeader();
            FillCalendar();
            DrawCalendar();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void DrawHeader()
        {
            Console.Write("\n\n");
            //gives you the month and year at the top of the calendar
            Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month) + " " + year);
            Console.WriteLine("Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su");
        }

        static void FillCalendar()
        {
            int currentDay = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < calendar.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < calendar.GetLength(1) && currentDay <= totalDays; j++)
                {
                    if (i == 0 && day > j)
                    {
                        calendar[i, j] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (j != promptDay)
                        {
                            calendar[i, j] = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            calendar[i, j] = currentDay;
                        }
                        currentDay++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void DrawCalendar()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < calendar.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < calendar.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if (calendar[i, j] > 0)
                    {
                        if (calendar[i, j] < 10)
                        {
                            Console.Write(" " + calendar[i, j] + " ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write(calendar[i, j] + " ");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("   ");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i get all the weekdays and dates in a month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903663/how-do-i-get-all-the-weekdays-and-dates-in-a-month)

Comment: Why are you declaring your `int`s like that?

Comment: yh i tried that but it doesnt ask for user input?? how can i get that?

Comment: i edited to new code i was trying earlier,

Comment: please check that and see where i have gone wrong

Comment: your for-loop never runs because you never assign `int days` any value. By default it is `0`. So no values are added into your list. Don't you want to ask the user once for the "weekday" ? and not on every iteration ?

Comment: the output should be similar to this ---

Comment: Which day do you want to look at (Mon = 0, etc)? 1
The Tuesdays of the month are: 4 11 18 25

Comment: yes just once, and any day not just weekday

Comment: actually you could make your life very simple. Find the first day that is a Tuesday for example and then count up in steps of 7 until you overstep `totalDays`

Comment: i dont have to use tuesdays, i need the day and month based on user input and how could i implement what you have just suggested

Comment: i tried the duplicate you said at the start but it gives an error when i install console.write for user input to return weeday

Comment: So basically you want a method like `public static IEnumerable<int> GetDays(int year, int month, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) { DateTime value = new DateTime(year, month, 1); while (value.Month == month) { if (value.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek) { yield return value.Day; } value = value.AddDays(1); } }, right?`

Comment: Or if you're uncomfortable with `IEnumerable` and `yield`, maybe: `public static List<int> GetDays(int year, int month, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) { List<int> result = new List<int>(); DateTime value = new DateTime(year, month, 1); while (value.Month == month) { if (value.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek) { result.Add(value.Day); } value = value.AddDays(1); } return result; }`

Comment: i dont understand, can u just make some changes to the code i had given in the question

Comment: @J.Doe - I don't understand your code. But it seems like you *have* the `year` and the `month` and the `dayOfWeek` as user inputs and *want* to display the "day numbers" of each of the given `dayOfWeek`s in that month.

Comment: i changed the code based on people's suggestion, please look at the code now and my question

Comment: Well, your code doesn't compile. Please be sure to follow these suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i dont think you understood my question? is that correct

Comment: However, rather than displaying a calendar, you should ask for a
different day and output which dates in the month fall on that day.
An example of the output from this program could be:
Enter the day the first falls on (Mon = 0, etc): 5
How many days in the month? 31
Which day do you want to look at (Mon = 0, etc)? 1
The Tuesdays of the month are: 4 11 18 25

Comment: ^^^ i need to do this

Comment: @J.Doe - Well, if it's not "you *have* the `year` and the `month` and the `dayOfWeek` as user inputs and *want* to display the 'day numbers' of each of the given `dayOfWeek`s in that month.", then no, I don't understand your question.

Comment: ok i'll explain again, so basically i need user input on days in a month and month name, and day (mon,tues,wed,etc..) and then the ouput should display the dates for the day specified by the user, for example if the user entered monday and november the output should display the dates for the monday in november

Comment: @J.Doe - ah, you see? "Enter the day the first falls on (Mon = 0, etc)" is quite different from what you have.

Comment: yh i am sorry if it is a mess of a code, i am just a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code prints out all the days for a given `DayOfWeek`, yes it can be improved but it's just a starting point

**OutPut**

```
What is the year? : 2016
What is the name of the month? : dicembre
Monday
5 12 19 26
Thursday
1 8 15 22 29
Wednesday
7 14 21 28
Tuesday
6 13 20 27
Friday
2 9 16 23 30
Saturday
3 10 17 24 31
Sunday
4 11 18 25
```

Note that `dicembre` is `december` in Italian.

```
Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<int>> daysCount = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<int>>()
{
    { DayOfWeek.Monday, new List<int>() },
    { DayOfWeek.Thursday, new List<int>() },
    { DayOfWeek.Wednesday, new List<int>() },
    { DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new List<int>() },
    { DayOfWeek.Friday, new List<int>() },
    { DayOfWeek.Saturday, new List<int>() },
    { DayOfWeek.Sunday, new List<int>() },
};

Console.Write("What is the year? : ");
var year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("What is the name of the month? : ");
var monthName = Console.ReadLine();

var monthNumber = DateTime.ParseExact(monthName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;
var dayOfMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthNumber);

var date = new DateTime(year, monthNumber, 1);


for(int i = 0; i < dayOfMonth; i++, date = date.AddDays(1))
{

    if (daysCount[date.DayOfWeek] == null)
    {
        daysCount[date.DayOfWeek] = new List<int>();
    }

    daysCount[date.DayOfWeek].Add(date.Day);
}

foreach (var day in daysCount)
{
    Console.WriteLine(day.Key.ToString());
    foreach (var dayNumber in day.Value)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", dayNumber));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

}

Console.ReadLine();
```

---

### Variant to show only user specified day

Notice that `Sunday = 0`

```
var days = new List<int>();
Console.Write("What is the year? : ");
var year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("What is the name of the month? : ");
var monthName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Enter the day you want to see the dates for (Mon = 0, etc): ");
var promptDay = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

var monthNumber = DateTime.ParseExact(monthName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;
var dayOfMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthNumber);

var date = new DateTime(year, monthNumber, 1);


for(int i = 0; i < dayOfMonth; i++, date = date.AddDays(1))
{

    if ((int)date.DayOfWeek == promptDay)
        days.Add(date.Day);
}

foreach (var day in days)
{
    Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", day));

}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: how can i change it so it just displays the one day entered by the user, so just monday, etc...

Comment: plus i got an error at list<int> bit and the dictionary bits too

Comment: the type or namespace dictionary couldnt be found, are you missing a reference

Comment: same for list<int>

Comment: @J.Doe i've updated the answer, to resolve your error insert `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top

Comment: do you have email that i can save for future contact, as i am so grateful for this!!

Comment: @J.Doe skype: daniaal.95

Comment: not skype? anything else i dont use skype, like gmail or something

Comment: sid9546 dot gmail dot com

Comment: i sent email to sid9546@gmail.com